# Accurate time-keeping in node.js

Tags: node.js, timing, beagleboneblack

I'm new to node.js, I'm trying to determine the elapsed time between an on and an off event of a switch (using BeagleBone Black), the script works, somewhat with .getTime() however from what I read it's not particularly accurate. So I did some research and attempted to use console.time, however from what I read there is no way to export the time value into a variable in this particular application.

I'm trying to write a script that times valve open and close events for an engine, so accuracy is paramount. The only input is a reed switch that is triggered by a passing magnet attached to a rotating flywheel.

More concisely, is there a way to time on/off events accurately in node.js?

```
var b = require('bonescript');

b.pinMode('P8_19', b.INPUT);
b.pinMode('P8_17', b.OUTPUT);
b.pinMode('USR3', b.OUTPUT);

b.attachInterrupt('P8_19', true, b.CHANGE, interruptCallback);

var cycle = 0;
//var t = 0;
var start, end;


function interruptCallback() {
     if (b.digitalRead('P8_19') == 1)
     {
    console.log('Magnetic field present!');
    cycle=cycle+1;
    console.log ('cycle: ' + cycle);
     }

    else
    {
    //console.time('t');
    start = (new Date()).getTime();
    }
    //console.timeEnd('t');
    //console.log(t);
    end = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log('elapsed time: ' + (end - start));
}
```

This is the full code that I'm currently using. Note: I've also displayed how I attempted to use console.time.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what accuracy would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most accurate time measure possible, use [`process.hrtime()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime). From the documentation:

> Returns the current high-resolution real time in a [seconds,
>   nanoseconds] tuple Array. It is relative to an arbitrary time in the
>   past. It is not related to the time of day and therefore not subject
>   to clock drift. The primary use is for measuring performance between
>   intervals.

The function returns a two-element array that contains the count of seconds and count of nanoseconds. Passing one time object into another will return the difference between the two objects.

For your case:

```
function interruptCallback() {
  if (b.digitalRead('P8_19') == 1) {
    cycle = cycle + 1;
  } else {
    start = process.hrtime();
  }
  end = process.hrtime(start);
  console.log('elapsed time: ' end[0] + ' seconds and ' + end[1] + 'nanoseonds.');
};
```